# Filter Columns Based on Variable in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains historical accounting data.  The table is arranged similar to my example below.

What I would like to do is select the FiscYr and PtdBal column based on a variable.  To make things even more complex, I need to somehow display the prior year PtdBal number as well.

For example, if I select 2016 there would be a column with the period I chose for both 2016 and 2015.

[image]

This is what it would look like after selecting the year and column with a variable.

http://i55.photobucket.com/albums/g131/jtwendel/Mobile%20Uploads/Capture_zpsozyiznzl.png

Comment: Well, good luck writing the query. If you have any problems, ask a question.

Comment: Can you share your desired results if you were to 'select 2016' given your sample data. That will help us better understand how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if below is your desire output...

```
DECLARE @YEAR int = 2016

SELECT FiscYr, PtdBal 
FROM your_table
WHERE FiscYr = @YEAR
    OR FiscYr = (@YEAR-1)
```